# Format the inserted date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

how can we format the date when you insert it into a collection in MongoDB ?

```
db.collection('transactions').insertOne({
            amount: 1,
            id: req.params.userid,
            date: new Date ()

        })
```

I tried things like

```
new Date (<YYYY-mm-dd>)
new Date ("<YYYY-mm-dd>")
```

But it doesn't work.

Google isn't really helping either.

Thank you

Comment: Not possible for formatting. You are inserting the Date object. Unless you are storing the date as string, or formatting you mean is to query the data and format the date field then it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with `Date` type

[Reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Date/#date--)

> new Date() returns the current date as a Date object. mongosh wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper. The ISODate is in
> UTC

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a representable date range of about 290 million years into the past and future.

On the other hand, you could do the below things

1. You can either use String type, but you need to convert to date before doing any queries

or

2. You need to convert to the desired format before returning to the client.